# check if record columns have some special values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to check to see if some of the fields have some unique values - for instance, I want to check if field1, field2 in my table have a value of "YES".  If both of them have "Yes" then I want to call some function, but if one of them has "No" value then I want to call some other function. Note in my select statement, I am passing an ID from the query-string.  How can I do this?

```
protected void Check_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e) {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Field1, Field2 from MyTabel WHERE ID = '" + Request.QueryString["ID"] + "'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If figuring out **whether** a specific **set of criteria exists** or not in a given record is all you need, then I can suggest you doing this check on Database side and then using `ExecuteScalar` to get the result:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) from MyTabel WHERE ID =@ID And (Field1='Yes' And Field2='Yes')" , con))
    {
        cmd.parameters.Add("@ID",Request.QueryString["ID"]);

        con.open();

        int result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        con.close();

        if(result == 1)
            // condition exists
            // so call success function
        else
            // call failure function
    }
}
```

*Update:*

This may not be directly related to the question but to get record Id from `detailsView`, you need to go through 2 steps:

1. Set the `datakeynames` property for the `detailsView` to the name of your table's primary key name – in this case, `ID`.

   ```
   <asp:detailsview datakeynames="ID"
   ```
2. Now you can access the selected Id by

   ```
   int id = (int)detailsView.SelectedValue;
   ```

Check here for more [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.selectedvalue.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your quick response but i am getting an error that reads like this: "Cannot implicitly convert type object to int"   at this line:  cmd.ExecuteScalar(),

Comment: sorry , I forgotted to cast it to int . check the answer now

Comment: thanks again, that error is fixed but getting another error now which reads like this: "ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed"

Comment: i think i fixed but will see if i get another error:  cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        int result =(int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: sorry , I wrote the code from old memory as I haven't written database codes for a while . I updated it again . anyway you should start using ORMs if you haven't yet .

Comment: thank you so much this worked great.  I have one small request and i hope you can help me.  Instead of getting the ID from the QueryString, how can i access it from the DetailView?  thanks in advance for your time